# socket io making anonymous eio=2 calls

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have pretty much been learning from the tutorial posted here.
http://www.williammora.com/2013/03/nodejs-tutorial-building-chatroom-with.html

and when I was done I kept on getting this after any socket.io connection:

/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1407300527964-0
/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1407300527984-1&sid=NODtj47CA4mdxjdjAAAB
/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1407300528005-2&sid=NODtj47CA4mdxjdjAAAB
/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1407300528008-3&sid=NODtj47CA4mdxjdjAAAB

and eventually I was disconnected from socket, and the connection resets.

```
Connected NODtj47CA4mdxjdjAAAB index.js:28
incomingMessage Object {message: "sdfdfs", name: "Anonymous"} index.js:60
Unable to connect to server 
Error {type: "TransportError", description: ReferenceError, stack: (...), message: "parser decode error"}
 index.js:70
Connected BhMCUqxOsRBWrmPmAAAC
```

and I might have been installed the newest modules instead of the package.json

```
{
  "name": "chatTutorial",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.5.2",
    "express": "^4.7.4",
    "jade": "^1.5.0",
    "jshint": "^2.5.2",
    "socket.io": "^1.0.6",
    "underscore": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

here is the code if you are interested
server.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies:
 * - Express
 * - Http (to run Express)
 * - Body parser (to parse JSON requests)
 * - Underscore (because it's cool)
 * - Socket.IO (Note: we need a web server to attach Socket.IO to)
 */

var express = require("express")
  , app = express()
  , http = require("http").Server(app)
  , bodyParser = require("body-parser")
  , _ = require("underscore")
  , io = require("socket.io")(http)
  ;

/**
 * The list of participants in our chatroom. The format of each participants will be:
 *  {
 *      id: "sessionId",
 *      name: "participantName"
 *  }
 */

/* Server config */
var participants = [];

//Server's IP address
app.set("ipaddr", "127.0.0.1");
//Server's port number 
app.set("port", 8080);


// Specify a views folder
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
// View engine is Jade
app.set("view engine", "jade");
// Specify where the static content is
app.use(express.static("public", __dirname + "/public"));


//Tells server to support JSON requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());



/* Server routing */

//Handle route "GET /", as in "http://localhost:8080/"
app.get("/", function(request, response) {

  //Show a simple response message
  // response.send("Server is up and running");
  response.render("index0");

});


app.post("/message", function (req, res) {

    console.log('getting request', req.body);

    // The request body expects a param named "message"
    var message = req.body.message;

    // If the message is empty or wasn't sent it's a bad request
    if(_.isUndefined(message) || _.isEmpty(message.trim())){
        // return res.json(400, {error: "Message is invalid"}); //deprecated
        return res.status(400).json({error: "Message is invalid"});
    }

    // We also expect the sender's name with the message
    var name = req.body.name;

    // Let our chatroom know there was a new message
    io.sockets.emit("incomingMessage", {message: message, name: name});

    // Looks good, let the client know
    // res.json(200, {message: "Message received"}); //deprecated
    res.status(200).json({message: "Message received"});
});

/**
 * Socket.IO events
 */
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    /**
     * When a new user connects to our server, we expect an event called "newUser" and then we'll emit an event called "newConnection" with a list of all participants to all connected clients
     */
    socket.on("newUser", function(data){
        participants.push({id: data.id, name: data.name});
        console.log("newUser: ", data.name);
        io.sockets.emit("newConnection", {participants: participants});
    });

    /**
     * When a user changes his name, we are expecting an event called "nameChange", 
     * and then we'll emit an event called "nameChanged" to all participants with the id and new name of the user who emitted the original message
     */
    socket.on("nameChange", function (data) {
        console.log("nameChange: ", _findWhere(participants, {id: socket.id}).name, data.name);
        _.findWhere(participants, {id: socket.id}).name = data.name;
        io.sockets.emit("nameChanged", {id: data.id, name: data.name});
    });

    /**
     * When a client disconnects from the server, the event "disconnect" is automatically captured by the server. It will then emit an event called "userDisconnected" to all participants with the id of the client that disconnected
     */
    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
        participants = _.without(participants, _.findWhere(participants, {id: socket.id})
        );
        io.sockets.emit("userDisconnected", {
            id: socket.id,
            sender: "system"
        });
    });

});

//Start the http server at port and IP defined before
http.listen(app.get("port"), app.get("ipaddr"), function() {
  console.log("Server up and running. Go to http://" + app.get("ipaddr") + ":" + app.get("port"));
});
```

index.js:

```
    function init () {
    var serverBaseUrl = document.domain;

    /**
     * ON client init, try to connect to the socket.IO server. 
     * Note we don't specify a port since we set up our server to run on port 8080
     */
    var socket = io.connect(serverBaseUrl);

    // We'll save our session ID in a variable for later
    var sessionId = '';

    //Helper function to update the participants' list
  function updateParticipants(participants) {
        $('#participants').html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
            $('#participants').append('<span id="' + participants[i].id + '">' + participants[i].name + ' ' + (participants[i].id === sessionId ? '(You)' : '') + '<br /></span>');
        }
    }


    /**
     * When the client successfully connects to the server, an event "connect" is emitted. Let's get the session ID and log it.
     * Also, let the socket.IO server know there's a new user with a session ID and a name. We'll emit the "newUser" event for that.
     */
    socket.on("connect", function(){
        sessionId = socket.io.engine.id;
        console.log("Connected " + sessionId);
        socket.emit("newUser", {
            id: sessionId,
            name: $("#name").val()
        });
    });

    /**
     * When the server emits the "newConnection" event, we'll reset the participants section and display the connected clients. Note we are assigning the sessionId as the span ID.
     */
    socket.on("newConnection", function(data){
        updateParticipants(data.participants);
    });

    /**
     * When the server emits the "userDisconnected" event, we'll remove the span element from the participants element
     */
    socket.on("userDisconnected", function (data) {
        $("#"+data.id).remove();
    });

    /**
     * When the server fires the "nameChanged" event, it means we must update the span with the given ID accordingly
     */
    socket.on("nameChanged", function (data) {
        $("#"+data.id).html(data.name + " " + (data.id === sessionId ? "(You)" : "") + "<br />");
    });

    /**
     * When receiving a new chat message with the "incomingMessage" event, we'll prepend it to the messages section
     */
    socket.on("incomingMessage", function (data) {
        console.log("incomingMessage", data);
        var msg = data.message;
        var name = data.name;
        $("#messages").prepend("<b>"+name+"</b><br/>" + message + "<hr />");
    });

    /**
     * Log an error if unable to connect to server
     */
    socket.on("error", function (reason) {
        console.log("Unable to connect to server", reason);
    });

    /**
     * "sendMessage" will do a simple ajax POST call to our server with whatever message we have in our textarea
     */
    function sendMessage () {
        var outgoingMessage = $("#outgoingMessage").val();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/message",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                message: outgoingMessage,
                name: name
            })
        });
    }

    /**
     * If user presses Enter key on textarea, call sendMessage if there is something to share
     */
    function outgoingMessageKeyDown (event) {
        if(event.which == 13){
            event.preventDefault();
            if($("#outgoingMessage").val().trim().length <= 0){
                return;
            }
            sendMessage();
            $("#outgoingMessage").val("");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper function to disable/enable Send button
     */
    function outgoingMessageKeyUp(){
        var outgoingMessageValue = $("#outgoingMessage").val();
        $("#send").attr("disabled", (outgoingMessageValue.trim()).length > 0 ? false : true
        );
    }

    /**
     * When a user updates his/her name, let the server know by emitting the "nameChange" event
     */
    function nameFocusOut () {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        socket.emit("nameChange", {
            id: sessionId,
            name: name
        });
    }

    /**
     * Elements setup
     */
    $("#outgoingMessage").on("keydown", outgoingMessageKeyDown);
    $("#outgoingMessage").on("keyup", outgoingMessageKeyUp);
    $("#name").on("focusout", nameFocusOut);
    $("#send").on("click", sendMessage);


    // For debugging
    debo.socket = socket;
}

window.debo = {};

$(document).on('ready', init);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your handling of the "incomingMessage" event in your index.js. You are trying to parse an undefined "message" value instead of parsing the value of "msg". Therefore you get a "parser decode error". Change both variables to either "msg" or "message" and you won't get the error anymore.

```
socket.on("incomingMessage", function (data) {
    console.log("incomingMessage", data);
    var msg = data.message;
    var name = data.name;
    // "message" is undefined, you meant to read "msg"
    $("#messages").prepend("<b>"+name+"</b><br/>" + message + "<hr />");
});
```

Change it to:

```
socket.on("incomingMessage", function (data) {
    console.log("incomingMessage", data);
    var message = data.message;
    var name = data.name;
    $("#messages").prepend("<b>"+name+"</b><br/>" + message + "<hr />");
});
```

Comment: good catch, i rewrote from scratch and it worked! thanks though